# Android, add noise cancelling to SpeechRecognizer

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, microphone, noise-reduction

I'm creating an Android app which based on vocal commands. The idea here is to apply a noise reduction filter to the mic before starting speech recognizer.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can look out this blog

https://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-enable-noise-cancellation-in.html.

Use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION instead of AudioSource.MIC, which will give you really good results and noise in the background will reduce very much.

The great thing about this solution is, it can be used with both AudioRecord and MediaRecorder class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good one. But how to set the record as an input for SpeechRecognizer?